# Mixing Nhibernate and ADO transactions?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, repository-pattern

I have a rather odd requirement due to a codebase I've inherited. The DAL is based on the Repository pattern however some of the repositories are coded using the SqlConnection/SqlCommand with straight SQL and parameterised queries and some are coded using NHibernate.

I need to perform a series of data manipulations that requires repositories from both divides and if it fails at any stage along the way it all needs to rollback. What is the best way to go about this?

System.Data exposes an IDbTransaction and NHibernate an ITransaction, are these 2 compatible in anyway? Could I run both transactions at the same time and then roll them both back if something goes wrong? Would TransactionScope help me in this scenario?

Comment: You could simply try it out... Or google it...

Answer (score 1):

nhibernate supports the **sql statement** as well!

I seem to remember the method

**NHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery**, it return **IQuery**( Actually it's **SQLQuery** )

and you can go on calling the method **List** or **UniteResult**

usually, the coders love using a k-v class named **Hashtable**

you can use the ITransaction in Nhibernate.

Answer (score 1):

TransactionScope will create a hook that will be honored by all components that go through ADO.Net. Since *all* ORMs go through ADO.Net, all of them will implicitly honor the TransactionScope. Code like NHibernate, or Linq, or EF or any ORM you pick cannot suppress this unless they explicitly suppress the TransactionScope by *explicitly* overriding the current scope with a new one.

The problem may be though the escalation of the transaction to a distributed transaction on the server due to multiple connections enrolling into it. This is a slippery subject, subject to SQL Server/.Net version, see [System.Transactions Integration with SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172070.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to have code similar to the following:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IRepositoryA _repoA;
    private readonly IRepositoryB _repoB;

    public void DoStuff(EntityA someEntityA, EntityB someEntityB)
    {
        try 
        {
             _repoA.Save(someEntityA);
             _repoB.Save(someEntityB);
             // commit all stuff here

        }
        catch
        {
             // rollback all stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

If that is indeed the case then you need to have some kind of UnitOfWork abstraction that both the repositories depend on and can reference for their respective transaction context.  It would be much easier if both repos used Nhibernate, or IDbConnection/DbTransactions, but since there is an intermingling you will have to do a bit more work.

You'll need to create a "GenericTransaction" that houses both a IDbTransaction and an ITransaction, and let your unit of work have a method that creates a new GenericTransaction.

The commit/rollback on the GenericTransaction will perform the respective action on the two transactions.

To do it right you will have to refactor your existing repos quite a bit... but I wouldn't recommend it any other way.